# Какой фреймворк на Python или Ruby лучше всего подходит для разработки сайтов-визиток с админкой?

Tags: python, ruby

Подходит ли для этих целей Django и Ruby on Rails, или они слишком избыточны? Какие еще есть фреймворки на соответствующих языках с более упрощенной архитектурой? Нужен простой сайт-визитка с админкой и функциональностью блога

Comment: Ну если выбирать из этих двух, то у джанго есть авто-генератор админки, у рельсов вроде нету. Конечно если нужно только создать пару статичных страниц и менять их время от времени через админку и блог, то django слишком жирно и бесполезно брать, смотрите в сторону flask.

Comment: Для Ruby например Padrino(https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework) или Espresso (https://github.com/slivu/espresso)

Comment: > Ну если выбирать из этих двух, то у джанго есть авто-генератор админки, у рельсов вроде нету.

лолшто? ActiveAdmin -- офигительный генератор

> то django слишком жирно и бесполезно брать, смотрите в сторону flask.

или Sinatra

Comment: ActiveAdmin на основе рельс, а тут человек фреймворк выбирает. По сути, можно написать быстренько свой генератор CRUD на основе моделей, благо инструментов полно

Comment: ActiveAdmin не прямо из коробки как я понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берите в зависимости от того, какой язык вы лучше знаете\любите\исповедуете. Для меня было проще попробовать django из за знакомства с питоном. И лично я не соглашусь с комментарием [@Vladimir Gordeev](/users/532/vladimir-gordeev) по поводу "жирности". А flask я бы рекомендовал попробовать. Больше свободы действий и прозрачности, и его удобней использовать для более сложных проектов. А самое лучшее никому не верить а сесть и написать, тем более что в любой доке как пример идет написание простого блога, хоть на всех фреймворках попробуйте, хватит и одного вечера.

Answer (score 1):

Espresso Framework фреймворк для Ruby. Ничего лишнего. Простота и скорость работы. Пример  с исходными текстами - http://espresso.mosalt.ru/